# auto return type for a C++ member function of a template class

Tags: c++, oop, templates

For the sake of readability I will simplify my problem into a nice toy example:

Let's say I have a template class `Box` which can hold a finite collection of objects of a given type (initialised as `Box<double, 10>`). The class has a member function called `expand(n)` which  should modify the box such that the capacity is higher. Since the `10` is a specification of class instance I believe it is reasonable for the method to return a new object instead (ex. `Box<double, 20>`, for the function argument `n` given `20`).

I am having problems with a proper signature for the method. What I have is:

```cpp
template <typename T, const unsigned int size>
Box Box<T, size>::expand(const unsigned int newsize) const {
```

Naturally, the problem is with the return type... I cannot just add `<T, newsize>` since the latter is not yet in the scope.

I have been trying to use a trailing return syntax:

```cpp
template <typename T, const unsigned int size>
auto Box<T, size>::expand(const unsigned int newsize) -> Box<T, newsize> const {
```

But something is wrong here and I get errors..
How should I modify it?

Comment: You're going to need to make `newSize` a template parameter.  You can't use function parameters for template parameters.

Comment: toy examples are good, but complete toy examples + error message are even better ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameters of template must be decided in compilation time, so you cannot use function arguments, which is decided in run time. You should add the parameter as template argument instead.

```
template <typename T, const unsigned int size>
struct Box {
    template<const unsigned int newsize>
    Box<T, newsize> expand() const;
};

template <typename T, const unsigned int size>
template <const unsigned int newsize>
Box<T, newsize> Box<T, size>::expand() const {
    return Box<T, newsize>();
}

int main() {
    Box<double, 10> b;
    Box<double, 20> b2 = b.expand<20>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things: first, the `const` position is wrong. The thing the const applies to is the thing on its left. In that case, it is the return type, but you initially had it on the member function.

```
template <typename T, const unsigned int size>
auto Box<T, size>::expand(const unsigned int newsize) const -> Box<T, newsize> {
    // ...
}
```

Then, you try to use `newsize`, which is strictly a runtime value. You cannot use a runtime value in a context that require a constant expression. You will have to pass the size in a template parameter, since the language don't support function parameters to be marked as `constexpr`.

```
template <typename T, const unsigned int size>
template <unsigned int newsize>
auto Box<T, size>::expand() const -> Box<T, newsize> {
    // ...
}
```